# Why Can't I Sort by Instances of My Object?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort through an object, `players`, by the average score of each individual player - then return the top 3 players in an array.

I'm getting `sort is not a function` which makes me think I'm not calling it on the proper data type (I'm trying to sort by a number, called 'average').

I've tried to write the function in a number of ways, hoping to access the `average` property of the `player` in `players` but keep getting `sort is not a function`.

Below is my code (excluding functions that already work):

```
class Player {
    constructor(player_id, score) {
        this.player_id = player_id;
        this.scores = [score];
        this.total = score;
        this.average = this.averageScore();
    }

    averageScore() {
        return this.scores.length ? this.total / this.scores.length : 0;
    }

};

class LeaderBoard {

    constructor() {
        this.players = {};
    }

    top = (num_players) => {
      var sorted = this.players.sort((a, b) => (a.average > b.average) ? 1 : -1)
      return sorted.slice(0, num_players);
    }

};
```

I'd like for it to return an array of the indexes 0 through `num_players` after they've been sorted by their averages, but instead I'm getting `sort is not a function` - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `this.players` players is an object. And Objects donot have `sort()` neither `slice()`. Can you please tell how you are creating `this.players`?

Comment: How does `this.players` looks like  before you are calling the `sort()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to get the `players` in an array ... Object.values(this.players) will do that

then you can sort and slice

In a single line of code that would be

```
top = (num_players) => Object.values(this.players)
                       .sort((a, b) => (a.average - b.average))
                       .slice(0, num_players);
```

as a bonus: I'd declare Player like

```
class Player {
    constructor(player_id, score) {
        this.player_id = player_id;
        this.scores = [score];
        this.total = score;
    }

    get average() {
        return this.scores.length ? this.total / this.scores.length : 0;
    }

};
```

make `average` property a *getter* - should work just as well as your current code

here's a runnable snippet combining my previous answer with this one

```js
class Player {
    constructor(player_id, score) {
        this.player_id = player_id;
        this.scores = [score];
        this.total = score;
    }

    addScore(score) {
        this.total += score;
        this.scores.push(score);
        return score;
    }

    get average() {
        return this.scores.length ? this.total / this.scores.length : 0;
    }

    resetScore() {
        this.scores = [];
        this.score = 0;
    }

};
class LeaderBoard {
    constructor() {
        this.players = {};
    }
    addScore(player_id, score) {
        if (!this.players[player_id]) {
            this.players[player_id] = new Player(player_id, score);
        } else {
            this.players[player_id].addScore(score);
        }
        return this.players[player_id].average.toFixed(1);
    }
    top = (num_players) => Object.values(this.players)
                           .sort((a, b) => (a.average - b.average))
                           .slice(0, num_players);

    topids = (num_players) => Object.values(this.players)
                           .sort((a, b) => (a.average - b.average))
                           .map(({player_id}) => player_id)
                           .slice(0, num_players);
};
let x = new LeaderBoard();
x.addScore(1, 8);
x.addScore(2, 3);
x.addScore(3, 1);
x.addScore(4, 4);
console.log(x.topids(2));
console.log(x.top(2));
```

Comment: Does Object.values automatically return the array or should I assign it to  variable then return? I'm getting undefined

Comment: Please check the fully functional runnable snippet I just added @James

Comment: Thanks @Jaromando, last thing is that it's returning an array of arrays when I just need the player_id added to the arrays after sort is ran

Comment: actually it isn't an array of arrays, it's an array of objects - each object having a player_id property

Comment: So now I should be able to loop through it and return the player_id of each object no?

Comment: @James - I've added `topids` to show how easy that was :p

Comment: why would that happen? isn't the order correct in the answer?

Comment: that makes NO sense ... perhaps you want `b.average - a.average` to reverse the sort?

Comment: `(a.average > b.average) ? 1 : -1` in your question is equivalent to `a.average - b.average` - which is why I went that way :p

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are having object `this.players` with keys as names of players. And you want to get object as result. If that's the case use `Objects.keys` to get top 3 and then use `reduce()` to convert back to object.

```
var sorted = Object.entries(this.players)
                           .sort(([,v1], [,v2]) => v1.average - v2.average)
                           .slice(0,num_players)
                           .reduce((ac,[k]) => ({...ac,[k]:this.players[k]}),{})
```

Comment: I'm getting an `Unexpected token '.' for the last `this.players`

Comment: @James Fixed that check it now.

Comment: strange, I'm getting undefined as with the other proposed solution

Comment: @James Can you create a snippet where you are getting `undefined`?

Comment: @Maheer_Ali `console.log('Top 3 [' + leader_board.top(3) + '])` returns: Top 3 [undefined]. (Not sure if this is what you meant)

Comment: @James Can't say anything whithout knowing how `this.players` looks like.